# $k[\epsilon]\to k$ is not a flat ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $k[\epsilon]:=k[x]/(x^2)$ the ring of dual numbers. Suppose that we have a map
$$
k[\epsilon]\to k,
$$
$$
a+b\epsilon \mapsto a.
$$
How can we see that this map not flat, i.e., does not make $k$ into a flat $k[\epsilon]$-module? It seems that $k$ is a torsion-free module. I would particularly appreciate a direct algebraic proof.

Comment: Have you tried checking some exact sequences?

Comment: @Dzooks I have tried $0\to (t^2) \to k[t] \to k[\epsilon]\to 0$, but this did not get me anywhere

Comment: What about $0\to k \to k[\epsilon] \to k \to 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what *direct algebraic* means exactly, but I feel this is *direct*:

Hint: $k[\epsilon]$ is local:

What does that say about the f.g. flat modules?

What submodules of $k[\epsilon]$ can be summands?

From this you should be able to see why.

Comment: Thanks! By 'direct algebraic' I meant something not taking Spec or Tor.

Answer (score 2):

To spell out @xarles's suggestion in the comment section above: the $k[\epsilon]$-linear map $(\epsilon) \to k[\epsilon]$, $$a\epsilon \mapsto a\epsilon,$$ with $a\in k[\epsilon]$,  is injective. However, if one tensors with $k = k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon)$, the resulting map is the zero map, with a non-zero domain:  that is, $(\epsilon) \otimes_{k[\epsilon]} k \simeq k$, while its image in $k[\epsilon]\otimes_{k[\epsilon]} k$ is $0$.

In other words, one can move  $\epsilon$ across the tensor product in the image (where $\epsilon\otimes 1 = 1 \otimes \epsilon = 0$), but not in the domain.